# Location Picker for Android

Tags: android, location

I want users to let them pick a custom location, latitude and longitude. It should work offline.

What are the Best User friendly(Pictorial) ways to do it ?.

(I do not want to give simply a text box to feed the latitude and longitude.)

Comment: what do you mean by offline ?

Comment: And how exactly are you going to let users have a pictorial representation of an input for -any- lat/long without having the equivalent of the whole of Google maps stored offline?

Comment: @gtumca-MAC Offline means not connected to the internet . So no google maps i guess

Comment: Have you considered [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)?

Comment: @Guykun Any earth image should do, It doesnt need to be that detailed.

Comment: @Rajesh too complex and detailed for my requirements. I only want to find a UI pattern that would be intuitive and quick to select coarse location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did this once long before phones were smart... i took a good size and nice looking [mercator projection](https://www.google.com/search?q=mercator%20projection) mapped the coordinates roughly using some basic algebraic equations.  eg. pixel at {127, 578} -> Lat/Lon... Then just allowed them to click (tap in your case) on the image and drop a "pin" on the pixel they selected displaying the Lat/Lon in two text boxes...

for fanciness if the internet is available you could get a general "region" for that associated Lat/Lon (eg. nearest city/state)...

this concept should work perfectly for you... hope that helps -ck

Comment: Thanks exactly on the lines i was looking for. I was worried about this transformation. I guess this mercator projection is a good start.

Comment: @Alok Mercator makes life easy, because not only is the map result in a rectangle which is easy to stick in a UI, but there's no more log of something to the power of something to resolve the spherical coordinates, for added fun you could color test the pixel to make sure they chose land instead of water...